# Cocoa App with Visual Studio mac - Programmatically Create NSButton on a button click with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, nsbutton

I am at beginner level in mac programing. I am trying to generate a button on a button click. There isn't any error in the console but on-click the button is not appearing in the current view. Please guide me in a right way. Thanks in advance!

Here is my current code:

```
partial void AddButton(NSButton sender)
    {

        NSButton custombutton = new NSButton
        {

            BezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.Rounded,
            Title = "test"

        };
        custombutton.FitToSize();

        View.AddSubview(custombutton);
        Console.WriteLine("Button Has been added");
    }
```

Comment: What is the frame of the button?

Comment: @Willeke are you talking about this "Frame = (0,0,0,0)" ?

Comment: Yes, you can't see the button if the width and height are 0.

Comment: Exactly. I've added this custombutton.fittosize(); and its working now. Thank you @Willeke, your comment realize me what was missing. Thanks again for the help. :)